# unable to run opencv with cuda 7.0

Tags: opencv

I have tried to build and run OpenCV on Ubuntu 14.04. I have previously installed CUDA 7.0 (which is working perfectly with other programs) and when I try to run openCV (opencv_traincascade) I get the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.6.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I understand correctly, OpenCV expects CUDA v6.5 which is not installed. Does anyone know how to install OpenCV with CUDA 7.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. try to find **libcudart.so.6.5**, use **find** or **locate** command, make sure it exists or link to the file exists.
2. then add path to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile(or sth else, I add it to bashrc on Ubuntu), like:

   **PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin:$PATH**

   **LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH**

   if you change your path to install cuda, use your real path instead.